# Find sum of data from the latest date in bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like so:

```
    ID   | Date        | Language
    ---------------------------------
    A    | 2013-04-10  | EN
    A    | 2013-04-11  | EN
    A    | 2013-05-12  | SN
    B    | 2013-04-01  | SN
    B    | 2013-05-28  | SN
    .... (and many more dates for other ID)
```

I want the query to pick up the **LATEST Date for each ID, pick the Language for that code, and so on for all the records, and sum it up from all backlog data to LATEST Date**. So for the data above, the result should be **1 + 1  = 2 for EN and 1 for SN language, for ID = A** and so goes for the other IDs. I've found almost same question on S/O but in LINQ query ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015682/linq-sum-of-entries-based-on-latest-date)), not sure how to do in standard sql.

This is what I've been trying (`up only to sum all data without putting WHERE clause for latest date`):

```
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        Date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sum_EN, #count all language from latest date of each ID
        SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'SN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sum_SN,
    FROM t 
    #WHERE Date from latest date to all backlog data 
    GROUP BY ID, Date
```

Sample output:

```
    ID   |   Date      | Sum_EN | Sum_SN
    --------------------------------------
    A    | 2013-05-12  | 2      |   1
    B    | 2013-05-28  | 0      |   2
    .... (and many more dates for other ID)
```

Note: I comment WHERE clause in query because not sure how to select for latest date for each ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like max date for each Id, then you can add max date and it will give your expected output.

```
 SELECT 
        ID, 
        max(Date) Date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sum_EN, #count all language from latest date of each ID
        SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'SN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sum_SN,
    FROM t 
    #WHERE Date from latest date to all backlog data 
    GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT id, MAX(Date) as Date, ''' || (
  SELECT STRING_AGG("COUNTIF(Language = '" || Language || "') AS Sum_" || Language ORDER BY Language)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Language FROM `project.dataset.table`)
) || '''
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
''';
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id  Date        Sum_EN  Sum_SN   
1   A   2013-05-12  2       1    
2   B   2013-05-28  0       2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly based on the *result set*, then you want:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Date) as date,
       COUNTIF(Language = 'EN') AS Sum_EN, 
       COUNTIF(Language = 'SN') AS Sum_SN,
FROM t 
GROUP BY ID;
```

Your description, though, suggests:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Date) as date,
       COUNTIF(Language = 'EN') AS Sum_EN, 
       COUNTIF(Language = 'SN') AS Sum_SN,
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY ID;
```

However, this only grabs the data from the last date for each `id`, so I think you want the first version.